# ASP/VB6 to .Net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb6, asp-classic

```
oXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
oNode = oXML.createElement("CommonCustomerSearch")
oRoot = oXML.appendChild(oNode)
```

Looking for the equivalent for the code above in .Net 2.0. I found some sample code that seemed to be what I was looking for, but I believe it was using .NET_4 classes. I need a solution for 2.0.

Can someone post a .NET 2.0 equivalent of the above lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Xml;
XmlDocument oXML = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement oNode = oXML.CreateElement("","CommonCustomerSearch","");
XmlNode oRoot = oXML.AppendChild(oNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

using VB.NET would be something like ...

```
Imports System.Xml
Dim oXML as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument
Dim oNode as XmlElement = oXML.CreateElement("","CommonCustomerSearch","")
Dim oRoot as XmlNode = oXML.AppendChild(oNode)
```

hopefully this helps ...